# Android Background Process

Tags: android, android-service

[image: Processes]

I am wondering that why there is still a process running even I had already left(pressing back button) the Flickr and the Messenger apps in the picture above?

Recently I wrote an app that contains a service, I've found that if there is still a process running, the service will less likely be killed by the system.

So how does the apps above keep processes running in background?

Answer (score 0):

They uses background service that will stay alive even if you quit the app.. as the documentation said

```
The Android system will attempt to keep the process hosting a service around as long as the service has been started or has clients bound to it
```

As long the app is not ended service will stay alive unless there is no memory left.

```
 When running low on memory and needing to kill existing processes, the priority of a process hosting the service will be the higher of the following possibilities:

If the service is currently executing code in its onCreate(), onStartCommand(), or onDestroy() methods, then the hosting process will be a foreground process to ensure this code can execute without being killed.
If the service has been started, then its hosting process is considered to be less important than any processes that are currently visible to the user on-screen, but more important than any process not visible. Because only a few processes are generally visible to the user, this means that the service should not be killed except in extreme low memory conditions.
If there are clients bound to the service, then the service's hosting process is never less important than the most important client. That is, if one of its clients is visible to the user, then the service itself is considered to be visible.
A started service can use the startForeground(int, Notification) API to put the service in a foreground state, where the system considers it to be something the user is actively aware of and thus not a candidate for killing when low on memory. (It is still theoretically possible for the service to be killed under extreme memory pressure from the current foreground application, but in practice this should not be a concern.)
```

you can learn more about Service [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html)

Comment: So perhaps it's because there is a process bound to the service? Because in my app, as long as i leave the process, the running service list would show "0 process, 1 service"

Comment: @shockwave yes service will still be alive when leave the app.

Answer (score 0):

The back button doesn't end the app, its like minimizing them in Windows.  TO end them they need to be call finish.  Androiud's design (which I think is a stupid, insecure idea, but its how it works) is that apps will not exit unless they exit themselves with finish or you run low on memory and the OS kills them.